# Returning a vector from a function

Tags: c++

So I wrote a class in a header file called: `main.h` and I want to return the vector after calling the function. So here is the code for the header file:

```
//main.h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T1>
class LSR {
    public:
        std::vector<T1> arr;

        LSR(std::vector<T1> ARR) {
            arr = ARR;
        }


        // template <typename T2>
        void output() {
            for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        template <typename T2>
        int search(T2 to_find) {
            for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr[i] == to_find) { return i; }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        template <typename T3>
        T1 replace(T3 to_find, T1 to_replace) {
            int value = search(to_find);
            if (value > -1) {
                for (int x=0; x<arr.size(); x++) {
                    arr[x] = to_replace;
                }
                return std::vector<T1> arr; <-- error here
            }
            return NULL;
        }

};
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> board = {
        "Hello", "there", 
        "how", "are", "you"
    };

    LSR<std::string> L1(board); 
    L1.replace("you", "yeah ya");
    std::cout << board[4] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I have tried 2 things that I can think of but it didn't work:

1. just returning `arr` but that didn't work, it has the following errors:
   `expected primary-expression before 'arr'`
   `expected ';' before 'arr'`
2. Returning `std::vector<T1>` only, with the following error:
   `expected primary-expression before ';' token`

I am unsure what I need to do to solve this problem, as I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Why is everything in the class using its own `template`, instead of using the main `template` on the class itself?

Comment: Returning `arr` is redundant, I should think, if you've already modified it.

Comment: Also, you can't return `arr` without changing the return type, because the return type is `T1` and `arr` is of type `std::vector<T1>`. Additionally, when you pass `board` into the constructor, it's copied into `arr`, so `board[4]` would be the same. It's not like Java where only references are copied by default.

Comment: Also very misleading to `return NULL` when the expected type is `T1` - it may work depending what overloads etc are at play but it is horrible for the reader.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Look carefully. The constructor doesn't take `board` by reference, it takes it by value, creating a copy. So after `L1.replace(...)` was called, `L1.arr` has been modified, but `board` hasn't, so `board[4]` is still `"you"`.

Comment: Calling `replace` will make the vector `L1.arr` equal to `"yeah ya"` in all its components

Comment: @NathanPierson Which is exactly what I was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace()` can't return the entire `arr`.  For one thing, the syntax you are using is wrong, `return std::vector<T1> arr;` would need to be `return arr;` instead.  But `replace()` returns a `T1`, and `arr` is not a `T1` but a `std::vector<T1>` instead, so `return`'ing `arr` won't work.

In any case, there is no need to have `replace()` return anything at all, since it is modifying the contents of `this`.

Also, `replace()` is not actually replacing the found element correctly, it is replacing *all elements* in the `arr` if *any* of them match `to_find`.

You need to get rid of the loop altogether if you want to replace only the 1st matching element, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T3>
void replace(const T3 &to_find, const T1 &to_replace) {
    int value = search(to_find);
    if (value > -1) {
        arr[value] = to_replace;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, get rid of the `search()` call if you want to replace all matching elements, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T3>
void replace(const T3 &to_find, const T1 &to_replace) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < arr.size(); ++x) {
        if (arr[i] == to_find) {
            arr[i] = to_replace;
        }
    }
}
```

---

That being said, there is no reason to have all of the class methods use their own `template` parameters, since they all operate on the same type as the main `template` parameter of the class, so just use that one `template` by itself for everything, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class LSR {
    public:
        std::vector<T> arr;

        LSR(const std::vector<T> &ARR) {
            arr = ARR;
        }

        void output() const {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
                std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }

        int search(const T &to_find) const {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
                if (arr[i] == to_find) { return i; }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        void replace(const T &to_find, const T &to_replace) {
            // see further above...
        }
};
```

---

Also, the class constructor makes a *copy* of the `board` array, so when `main()` outputs `board[4]`, it is not going to see the result of `replace()`.  `main()` would have to access the modified `arr` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> board = {
        "Hello", "there", 
        "how", "are", "you"
    };

    LSR<std::string> L1(board); 
    L1.replace("you", "yeah ya");
    std::cout << L1.arr[4] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, change the class to keep a *reference* to the `board` vector, instead of making a *copy* of it, then `board[4]` will get modified as expected, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class LSR {
    public:
        std::vector<T> &arr;

        LSR(std::vector<T> &ARR) : arr(ARR) {}

        ...
};
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> board = {
        "Hello", "there", 
        "how", "are", "you"
    };

    LSR<std::string> L1(board); 
    L1.replace("you", "yeah ya");
    std::cout << board[4] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would note that the calling code would be advised to query `L1.arr[4]` instead of `board[4]` to see the effects of this replacement, because `L1` has its own copy of the vector and isn't changing `board`.

Comment: @NathanPierson added